# Logic to Add value in array in below pattern in efficient way, and can some one please tel what we call this array patterns

Tags: javascript, logic

let say we have array stored in an object in below format, please help me to write the logic for this.

```
let example output = {
   'a':['WO','WO','WO','M','M','M','M'],
   'b':['M','WO','WO','WO','M','M','M'],
   'c':['M','M','WO','WO','WO','M','M'],
   'd':['M','M','M','WO','WO','WO','M'],
   'e':['M','M','M','M','WO','WO','WO'],
   'f':['WO','M','M','M','M','WO','WO'],
   'b':['WO','WO','M','M','M','M','WO'],
   'c':['WO','WO','WO','M','M','M','M'],
   'd':['M','WO','WO','WO','M','M','M'],
   'e':['M','M','WO','WO','WO','M','M'],
}
```

Below

```
const generatedShift = (shift, totalNumberOfDays) => {
    const SHIFTS = ['M', 'A', 'N'];
    const shiftData = [];
    if (typeof shift === 'string' && shift.length === 1 && typeof totalNumberOfDays === 'number') {
        if (SHIFTS.includes(shift.toLocaleUpperCase()) && totalNumberOfDays) {
            for (let dd = 0; dd < totalNumberOfDays; dd++) {
                shiftData.push(shift);
            }
            return shiftData;
        } else {
            console.log('Please pass valide shift/days, argument passed for shift/days is false not appropirate');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('argument passed for shift/days is not appropirate');
    }
}
shift = generatedShift('M', 7);
```

**above logic will generate ['M','M',... 7 times]**
below logic will add WO but there is something wrong in my logic
so far i have written this and stuck in this logic

```
let indexToStartWO=0;
let noOfWO = 3;
let noOfM = 4;
for (let w = indexToStartWO; w < shift.length; w = w + noOfWO + noOfM) {
 console.log("w", w);
  shift.splice(w, noOfM, 'WO', 'WO', 'WO');
}
indexToStartWO++;
```

like wise it should keep repeating for new object entry, with having similar array pattern value repeating, **(please help me to know this pattern name) can we call it round robin**? **Please help to write this logic**

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: i have modified the post please have a look @Andreas

Answer (score 1):

- We can use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert `i` from a number to a letter if we iterate between `97` and `122`.
- To create the array pattern we initialise a new array that looks like this `["WO" x3, "M" x 4]` and move the last item to the front of the array on each iteration

**Code:**

```js
let terms = [
    ...Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 'WO'),
    ...Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => 'M'),
];

let example = {};

for (let i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
    example[String.fromCharCode(i)] = terms.slice(0, 8);
    terms = [terms[terms.length - 1], ...terms.slice(0, -1)];
}

console.log(example) //> 
/* 
{
    a: ['WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    b: ['M', 'WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    c: ['M', 'M', 'WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M'],
    d: ['M', 'M', 'M', 'WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M'],
    e: ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'WO', 'WO', 'WO'],
    f: ['WO', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'WO', 'WO'],
    g: ['WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'WO'],
    h: ['WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    i: ['M', 'WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    ...
};
*/
```

**Demo:**

```js
let terms = [
    ...Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => 'WO'),
    ...Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => 'M'),
];

let example = {};

for (let i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
    example[String.fromCharCode(i)] = terms.slice(0, 8);
    terms = [terms[terms.length - 1], ...terms.slice(0, -1)];
}

// From here onwards `example` contains your target object, the code below this is just to show that.
//console.log(example)


(async() => {
   let entries = Object.entries(example)
   for ([key, value] of entries) {
      console.log(value, key)
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 200))
   }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, much easier approach

```
 let arr = ['WO', 'WO', 'WO', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M']
    let arr2 = []
    let first = "b", last = "z";
    var result = {};

    result['a'] = arr;
    for (let i = first.charCodeAt(0); i <= last.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
      arr2.push(arr[arr.length -1 ]);
      for (let j = 0; j < arr.length -1; j++) {
        arr2.push(arr[j]);
      }
      result[eval("String.fromCharCode(" + i + ")")] = arr2;
      arr = arr2;
      arr2 = [];

    }
    console.log( result );
```

in result variable, you will get your final output

if you want to do this pattern with different letters just change arr value it will work